# March 2019 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, moderators, announcement

The 2019 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

**Voting commences on March the 11th, at 20:00 UTC.**

Please visit the official election page at

https://stackoverflow.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on Meta—just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: As is tradition, people are trying to close this. As is also tradition, someone needs to post the comment saying not to do that. This time it's me - no need to close this. It's not something I care enough about to debate; post on mSE if you think these posts are unnecessary.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged "status-completed"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it has been closed and reopened in a short amount of time recently, so, indeed, maybe it need an extra tag, or a close, I am not sure what the usual approche is on meta for those.

Comment: @Undo Huh. Wonder why?