# Do we really need a meta post about each election?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Do we really need a [post on meta about the upcoming election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380884/2019-community-moderator-election)? As far as I can tell,  the [*Upcoming events*](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) already tells us there's an election, and I believe that hangs around until the end of the election.

Furthermore, the meta post really only says the following:

- The election is happening right now
- There are 3 phases
- The time an election takes
- How to ask questions about the election
- Links to the election itself

The [election itself](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) covers in my opinion all of this information:

- Election start + end date
- The 3 phases
- How to ask questions about the election (although the post says it take these with [election](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/election) the event does not).

So it doesn't mention how long each election goes for, but it does contain a start and end date. The *question* on meta just takes up a slot in hot meta posts, and truthfully there's already enough there about an election, I'm sure no one will miss it:

[image]

The post seems to take time away from people, as you'll notice people voting to close it and a moderator has had to leave a comment.

I'm not trying to ruin anyone's fun, but I really don't think we need the post on meta about the election. There's already enough information to draw everyone's attention there is an election, and it wastes space in the hot meta post and costs some people's time dealing with close voters etc.

<sub>Not actually inspired by [Undo's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380884/2019-community-moderator-election#comment674969_380884), I wanted to ask about this since I first saw it. I tried downvoting the question in hopes it wouldn't appear in hot meta posts, but alas</sub>

Comment: If the software didn't automatically create one, people would manually create one or many to discuss it.  Putting all of the discussion in one place likely makes it *easier* to avoid if you're not interested in it.

Comment: It would be more useful if there was information specific to the particular election in the post: number of open spots, dates.

Comment: The irony is that this adds one more Meta post to the pile.

Comment: *"as you'll notice people voting to close it and a moderator has had to leave a comment"*. Yeah. I'm going to be honest: this whole post is making a mountain out of a molehill.

Comment: @Tas For what it's worth, I'm a new SO user, this is my first election, and I found the post a helpful pointer.

Answer (score 35):

> Furthermore, the meta post really only says the following

It says all those things because *people ask those questions repeatedly* during the election. Presumably *after* reading the election page.

Repetition is essential to a quality education; folks often ask questions that are already documented thoroughly. You may even see this on Stack Overflow itself once in a while!

Comment: I wonder who is supposed to be educated by seeing too-heavily-duplicated questions...